# Why can't I click on those links? Very annoying css/html bug

Tags: html, css

A friend asked me to add some dropdown menus to his site. It's here: http://importingacartospain.com/

For some reason I can't click the dropdown links. I must be missing something. Can anyone please check it out?

Thanks!

Comment: Among other issues you're including two versions of jQuery.

Comment: Auch :) two jQs? whhaaa! this is not my code btw, I'm just hard-codding a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `return false;` on line 43 of tabs.js returning false cancels the behavior of the event, in this case clicking on a link.

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle & Ivan Guardado Castro
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                    
/***************************/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu > li").click(function(e){
        switch(e.target.id){
            case "news":
                //change status & style menu
                $("#news").addClass("active");
                $("#tutorials").removeClass("active");
                $("#links").removeClass("active");
                //display selected division, hide others
                $("div.news").fadeIn();
                $("div.tutorials").css("display", "none");
                $("div.links").css("display", "none");
            break;
            case "tutorials":
                //change status & style menu
                $("#news").removeClass("active");
                $("#tutorials").addClass("active");
                $("#links").removeClass("active");
                //display selected division, hide others
                $("div.tutorials").fadeIn();
                $("div.news").css("display", "none");
                $("div.links").css("display", "none");
            break;
            case "links":
                //change status & style menu
                $("#news").removeClass("active");
                $("#tutorials").removeClass("active");
                $("#links").addClass("active");
                //display selected division, hide others
                $("div.links").fadeIn();
                $("div.news").css("display", "none");
                $("div.tutorials").css("display", "none");
            break;
        }
        //alert(e.target.id);

// * Returning false here is canceling the click event of your links.
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem in IE9 and Chrome.

This appears to be the offending code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://importingacartospain.com/wp-content/themes/AutoMagWp/jquery-fonteffect-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

But I would also suggest fixing structural/semantic errors, starting with: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fimportingacartospain.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler inside tabs.js is returning false so the event is not bubbled and the default action will not be taken on the link. Try removing the `return false;` statement.